# Use Google for OAuth in winform webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, oauth-2.0

I would like to use the built in webbrowser control in C# winform's to authenticate a user using Google's OAuth.  Everything I have been able to find has required the user to go through the login process in the webbrowser to get the access token, then paste that token into my application.  How can I automatically get that access token so the user doesn't need to copy/paste?

Answer (score 0):

Jon, 
Generally, the Bearer token is sent back in the html-response body as a JSON document.
For example, from the spec.

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Pragma: no-cache

  {
    "access_token":"mF_9.B5f-4.1JqM",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
  }
```

If this is the case, you can grab the response using the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted Event and then capturing the JSON using JavaScriptSerializer

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String json = webbrowser.DocumentText
TokenResponse token = jss.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(json);


   public class TokenResponse
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    }
```